# PHP if statement within array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have the following PHP array

```
$menu['Settings']['user'] = array(

    1=>'General',
    'database.php'=>'Database',
    'users.php'=>'User Management'

);
```

However the entry for database.php needs to depend on if a string called $user=="Admin"

Any idea how I can put an if statement inside this array?

Comment: Use a ternary statement: `'database.php'=> ($user === 'Admin') ? 'Database' : 'SomeOtherValue',`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [ternary operation](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary)?

```
'database.php' => $user === 'Admin' ? 'Database' : 'Grumblecakes',
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this outside of the array is much easier for beginners than a ternary operation.

```
$menu['Settings']['user'] = array(
    1=>'General',
    'database.php'=>'Database',
    'users.php'=>'User Management'
);

if($user == "Admin") {
    $menu['Settings']['user']['database.php'] = "";
}
```

Comment: What's hard about a ternary operation? What does it have to do with being a beginner, even?

Comment: It can be confusing for some people. I guess it'd be worth it for them to learn now, but some people I know actually prefer this method over ternary.